# D.Va.Defence Matrix: How is the damage blocked stat calculated?

Tags: overwatch

Most of the time it's pretty obvious how damage blocked is calculated. It's the damage of the incoming attack. But how is that calculated for ultimates? If I eat a Hanzo's Dragonstrike, Mei's Blizzard or Zarya's grav, how much damage is that calculated as?

Comment: As far as I can tell, ults prevented is tracked as a separate thing.  You occasionally see it in end game cards and as a Shutdown Play of the Game.

Comment: This seems straightforward to test. Jump into a custom with a friend and matrix one of each to see what the damage blocked stat shows.

Answer (score -3):

No sources, but here is how I think it's calculated.

No ability is straight a 'you die' ability, so everything has a damage value associated with it.

So when you absorb an ability with the Diva shield, it calculates how much damage has been stopped if that ability or attack would have connected.

And I haven't played in a while, but I'm pretty sure D.va wall cannot block things like the Hanzo or Zarya's Grav and the ability goes straight through and does full damage.

Comment: This is incorrect. DVa does not have a shield or a wall, she has a defence matrix that deletes projectiles. It cannot block the hanzo dragonstrike once the dragon has formed, but it can delete the arrow before it turns into a dragon, therefore cancelling the entire ability (I do this a lot to gravs and dragons).

One dragonstrike can deal anywhere from several thousand if you hit 6 tanks, or if everyone runs out the way it can deal tiny damage. Damage dealt by dragonstrike is 100% dependent on how long the enemy stays in it / how many stay in it. So how do you put a number on that?